# issue returning array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a drivers license test program where in the main method the user inputs the answers then in a separate class there needs to be a method to see if the user passed a method to tell how many were wrong and right and a method put the numbers of the answers which were wrong into an array then the main method needs to print out the results of each of those methods. my issues is with the array of the problem numbers that were wrong . I believe I correctly created it but I cant get the main method to print it out.Thanks

```
   public class DriverExam
   {
      static String[] correctAnswers={"b","d","a","a","c","a","b","a","c","d","b","c","d","a","d","c","c","b","d","a"};
      static String[] userAnswers=new String[20];


   //constructer
      public  DriverExam(String[] user)
      {
         userAnswers=user;
      }




   //method to see if you passed
      public static boolean passed()
      {
         boolean pass=false;
         int correctCount=0;
         int incorrectCount=0;
         for(int i=0;i<userAnswers.length;i++)
         {
            if(userAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i]))
            {
               correctCount++;
            }
            else
            {
               incorrectCount++;
            }
         }

         if(correctCount>14)
         {pass=true;}
         return pass;

      }

      //method to find number correct
      public static int totalCorrect()
      {
         boolean pass=false;
         int correctCount=0;
         int incorrectCount=0;
         for(int i=0;i<userAnswers.length;i++)
         {
            if(userAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i]))
            {
               correctCount++;
            }
            else
            {
               incorrectCount++;
            }
         }

         return correctCount;

      }

      //method to tell how many were not correct
      public static int totalIncorrect()
      {
         boolean pass=false;
         int correctCount=0;
         int incorrectCount=0;
         for(int i=0;i<userAnswers.length;i++)
         {
            if(userAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i]))
            {
               correctCount++;
            }
            else
            {
               incorrectCount++;
            }
         }

         return incorrectCount;

      }

      public static int[] questionsMissed()
      {

         boolean pass=false;
         int correctCount=0;
         int incorrectCount=0;
         for(int i=0;i<userAnswers.length;i++)
         {
            if(userAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i]))
            {
               correctCount++;
            }
            else
            {
               incorrectCount++;
            }
         }
      int[] questionWrong=new int[incorrectCount];

      for(int i=0;i<questionWrong.length;i++)
      {
      if(!userAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i]))
      {i=questionWrong[i];
      }
      }
      return questionWrong;
      }
      }

import java.util.Scanner;
public class DriverExamDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] userAnswers=new String[20];
String answer;

System.out.println("please enter the testee's answers as the correspond with the question number");

for(int i=0;i<userAnswers.length;i++)
{
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Q."+(i+1));
answer=input.next();
userAnswers[i]=answer;
}
// constructor to send the users answers
DriverExam exam1 = new DriverExam(userAnswers);

//Check passed boolean to see if the user passed or failed
if(DriverExam.passed())
System.out.println("you passed your driving exam");
else
System.out.println("you failed your driving exam");

//check how many answers were correct and incorrect
System.out.println("you answered "+DriverExam.totalCorrect()+" questions correctly");
System.out.println("you answered "+DriverExam.totalIncorrect()+" questions incorrectly");

int[] questionsWrong=DriverExam.questionsMissed();
for (int i=0;i<questionsWrong.length;i++)
{
System.out.println("you got question " +questionsWrong[i]+"incorrect");



}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please at least mention the Programming Language (and tag your question accordinly) ?

Comment: ...and press `<tab>` here and there...?

Comment: programming in java and I don't no what else id tag it in . I had a problem with an array so I tagged it as array im obviously new at this my bad

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line because it have no sense, you are assigning to loop control variable the value of an empty array.

```
i = questionWrong[i];
```

But, the whole algorithm that you are using to check the numbers of the wrong question is wrong, you should try with another one. With yours implementation you are only lopping on a subset of the total question, you should loop over all the questions, and get the numbers of the incorrect ones.

BTW, i think that you are making so much use of the static methods. In a broad sense is better use instance method, and for your case is perfectly valid. The use of instance methods in your case, allow make all the calculations in the constructor, or a method call by the constructor, and avoid duplicating the same code (the loops) all over the code.